# Chamisha Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred thirty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources,  if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(To the tune:) Two thirty-FIVE are the MONTHS in a *MACH-ZOR*.

...of nineteen years, that is.

Answer (score 6):

"Last night [which was Pesach]," Gideon argued to the angel who had just told him "G-d is with you," "Father read the Hallel, and I heard him say 'When Israel went out of Egypt...' But now G-d has abandoned us! If our ancestors were tzaddikim, let G-d help us in their merit. If they were wicked - why, then, just as He performed unearned miracles for them, let Him do the same for us. So 'where are all His wonders?'" (Rashi to Judges 6:13)

This was 235 years after the Exodus. (40 years in the desert + 28 of Yehoshua's leadership + 40 of Osniel ben Kenaz's + 80 of Ehud's + 40 of Devorah's + 7 years of Midianite oppression.)

Comment: Where do you come up with these?!?

Answer (score 1):

In a non-leap year, *Yom Yerushalayim* is the 235th day in the year if *Heshvan* is *Haser* (has 29 days) and *Kislev* is whole (has 30 days):

*Tishrei* - 30 days
*Heshvan* - 29 days
*Kislev* - 30 days
*Tevet* - 29 days
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar* - 29 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 28 days (*Yom Yerushalayim* is on the 28th day of *Iyar*)